# Adding robust standard errors to original panel model in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, plm

I use a within `plm` model:

```
model <- plm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=dataset, model="within", effect="twoways")
```

I detected heteroskedasticity and calculated robust standard errors with the `vcovHC` function from the `plm` package:

```
coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, method = "arellano"))
```

But unfortunately, I don't know how to "add" these robust standard errors to my original model. I do get the results with the `vcovHC` function:

```
t test of coefficients:

                               Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
x1                           0.04589038  0.02465875  1.8610  0.06317 **
x2                          -0.00065238  0.00027054  1.4114  0.01615 *
x3                          -0.00087420  0.00043580  1.0059  0.04525 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But it does not print the usual regression statistic like when I would run `summary(model)`:

```
Total Sum of Squares:    
Residual Sum of Squares: 
R-Squared:      
Adj. R-Squared: 
F-statistic:  , p-value:
```

So, I would like to find a way to merge the robust standard errors of the `vcovHC` function with my `plm` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest to have a look at the documentation: `?summary.plm`.
You will find explanation as well as an example that is easy to transfer to your requirement:

```
summary(model, vcov = function(x) vcovHC(x, method = "arellano"))
```